# Populate a UITableView with plist

Tags: uitableview, plist, swift

i'm trying to get a plist to populate uitableview

The plist looks like this :
[image]

the code i'm having trouble with :

```
class GravidMenu: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet
var tableView: UITableView
var dict = NSMutableArray(contentsOfFile: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("links", ofType: "plist"))
var txt : NSString = dict.valueForKey("menuPunkt") as NSString //this throws a error : GravidMenu.Type does not have a member named dict


func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.dict.count;
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {
    var cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell
    if let row = indexPath?.row {
        
        cell.textLabel.text = self.txt[row] // throws a error Nsstring does not have a a member named subscript
        println("Text \(txt)")
    }
    
    return cell
}
```

Seems like i'm getting closer.

---

### UPDATE

Showing Full code
with adjustments to cell.label and to var txt. also moved it some code to viewDidLoad which breaks it all it seems

```
import UIKit
import Foundation


class GravidMenu: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet
var tableView: UITableView

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var dict = NSMutableArray(contentsOfFile: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("links", ofType: "plist"))
    var txt : NSArray = dict.valueForKey("menuPunkt") as NSArray
    
    self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.dict.count; // Throws Error GravidMenu does not have a member named dict
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {
    var cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell
    if let row = indexPath?.row {
        
        cell.textLabel.text = "\(txt.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row))"
        println("Text \(txt)")
    }
    
    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
    println("You selected cell #\(indexPath.row)!")
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

---

### UPDATE

```
let dict : NSMutableArray! = NSMutableArray(contentsOfFile: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("links", ofType: "plist"))
var txt : NSArray! = dict?.valueForKey("menuPunkt") as? NSArray!
```

this is causing me trouble. it keeps saying that "GravidMenu has no member named dict" in the var txt line... anyone ? help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

all this code paste in viewDidLoad:

```
var dict : NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray(contentsOfFile: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("links", ofType: "plist"))
var txt : NSString = dict!.valueForKey("menuPunkt") as NSString
```

I'll search you the reason why you need to write in the viewDidLoad.

I recommend you put a question mark because you can not know if it will be nil, (if not find the file)

and also for dict!.

hope i helped :)

**UPDATE:**

```
    let dict : NSMutableArray! = NSMutableArray(contentsOfFile: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("links", ofType: "plist"))

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    var txt : NSString = dict!.valueForKey("menuPunket") as NSString;
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.dict!.count;
}
```

its work for me now.

Comment: hmm if i move it to viewDidLoad every item that has dict in it starts saying "GravidMenu does not have a member named dict"

Comment: updated the post to reflect changes. posted full code this time

Comment: how ever ! down at cell.labeltext.text doesn't work now.

Comment: got it working by moving var txt out of viewDidLoad. now how ever in var txt it says dict aint a member of GravidMenu. just posted it as answer. i'll update code to reflect